# Image hover with logo

Tags: image, sass, hover

I've been playing around with a css hover effect but I cannot figur out how I get the greyscale to work.

The hover effects works fine when hovering the "bg" image but when the cursor hits the "logo" image the greyscale of the "bg" stops.

I would like to have it working so only the "bg" is greyscale on hover and not the logo.

You can see it here http://codepen.io/Tonzr/pen/dNqVQQ

The HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <a href="" class="col-md-6">
      <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/331810/sample36.jpg" class="bg">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x90/000000?text=LOGO" class="logo">
    </a>

    <a href="" class="col-md-6">
      <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/331810/sample83.jpg" class="bg">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x90/000000?text=LOGO" class="logo">
    </a>

  </div><!-- END ROW -->
</div><!-- END CONTAINER -->
```

And here is the SASS

```
.col-md-6
  position: relative
  overflow: hidden
  width: 100%
  height: 25rem
  padding: 0
  .bg
    position: absolute
    left: 50%
    top: 50%
    height: auto
    width: 100%
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%)
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%)
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%)
    &:hover
      -webkit-filter: grayscale(90%)
      filter: grayscale(90%)
  .logo
    position: absolute
    top: 50%
    left: 50%
    margin-right: -50%
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YNOEMq

```
.col-md-6
  position: relative
  overflow: hidden
  width: 100%
  height: 25rem
  padding: 0

  &:hover .bg
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(90%)
    filter: grayscale(90%)
  ...
```

The problem is, if the cursor enters the logo element, the hover event propagation will not reach the bg element as they are siblings. So the solution is to catch the hover event at the parent anchor element, then affect the child bg.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you for clarifying that for me :)